# Video thumbnails in WPF

Tags: wpf, video, mvvm, mediaelement

I'm trying to add videos to my WPF project, but I can't find a proper solution for generating previews/thumbnails of the video. A lot of solutions on the internet mention you should play and then pause the video in code behind. I don't really like that solution especially because it gets very messy in combination with the MVVM structure of our project.

Another solution I thought of is generating a screenshot from the video and display that screenshot instead of the video, but I also have no success in creating the screenshots.

How do you guys show thumbnails of your videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by setting the **MediaPlayer**'s property of **ScrubbingEnabled** to true and still you need to move forward to capture any movie at real time.

For more samples, please read this nice blog entry by Clint Rutkas:

http://www.betterthaneveryone.com/archive/2009/10/02/882.aspx

Comment: Setting the loadedbehaviour to pause and scrubbing enabled does work indeed. Not the prettiest solution, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg.exe to generate thumbnail for your video as a jpg file,

```
ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg
```

Which is simpler way to do it, because by default we only show Thumbnail image and media element is hidden or inactive, and only when we click on it, we start playing the video. This also improves resource usage as media element is heavy if you are displaying multiple videos.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. Your solution would work, but i want the thumbnails to be generated automatically inside my application. Users can upload video's through a content management system. The application itself gets its information from the database and downloads te videos.

Comment: The best approach will be also to store thumbnail at a time of uploading at same location from where videos are downloaded. But I guess whatever solution you will choose that will be best for your application because I dont know full situation.